# Create extension method for Automapper AfterMap

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, extension-methods

I am using `Automapper` to map data from DbModel to ViewModel. We are saving data in db in UTC timezone. There are few cases when it's fine to display data int UTC and some cases when in Local Timezone.

So when flag is `true` I want to convert all datetimes to local timezone datetimes. For this I'm using `AfterMap`.

Basically it looks like this:

```
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DbModel>, IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(dbCollection, opt =>
            {
                if (convertToLocalDate)
                {
                    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => { Util.SetLocalDateAfterMap(dest); });
                }
            });
```

And `SetLocalDateAfterMap` looks like:

```
public static void SetLocalDateAfterMap<TDest>(TDest dest)
    {
        var descType = typeof(TDest);

        void SetLocalDate(object item)
        {
            var t = item.GetType();
            var types = new[] {typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTime?)};
            var props = t.GetProperties()
                .Where(p => types.Contains(p.PropertyType))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                object value = prop.GetValue(item, null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(item, ((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime());
                }
            }
        }

        if (descType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(descType))
        {
            foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)dest)
            {
                SetLocalDate(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SetLocalDate(dest);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to create extension method for mapper to use it like:

```
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DbModel>, IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(dbCollection).SetLocalDateAfterMap(convertToLocalDate);
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

Step 1:

```
public static [Your Data Class] SetLocalDateAfterMap<TDest>(this TDest dest)
```

Extensions method should use `this` keyword for create.

[Look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#:%7E:text=Extension%20methods%20enable%20you%20to,methods%20on%20the%20extended%20type.)

Comment: don't think it's so easy. As you can see `SetLocalDateAfterMap` is used inside `Action<>` that is passed as parameter into Automapper `Map` method

Comment: @demo it is not changing anything. You should do overload  to Extensions method

Comment: Ok, I can change `public static void SetLocalDateAfterMap<TDest>(TDest dest)` to `public static void SetLocalDateAfterMap<TDest>(this TDest dest)` and use it like `opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => { dest.SetLocalDateAfterMap(); });` but still it isn't what I want. Or I don't understand you.

Comment: @demo  We suppose `X` Type return from `Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DbModel>, IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(dbCollection)`. We added extensions method X class , thats why we can control our object. We operate on `X` class.  In Result `X.SetLocalDateAfterMap(convertToLocalDate);`.   `Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DbModel>, IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(dbCollection)` and `X` are Same Object Type

Comment: ok, got it. In other words I don't need Automapper `AfterMap` to set datetime as local. Maybe it's even better